# Why is an element only clickable with javascript or actions in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium

In the page below, I want to click the housing types menu so that I can select apartments and such. The menu is not revealed, but the code does not fail. It fails in the last line with the exception.

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

When I run the code in debug mode & click the menu manually, it passes. What is happening & why ?

```
public void dummy() {
    String url = "https://sfbay.craigslist.org/search/pen/apa?hasPic=1&search_distance=25&" +
            "postal=94014&nh=75&nh=80&min_price=1500&max_price=2500&bedrooms=1&bathrooms=1";
    browser.get(url);
    WebElement expand = browser.findElement(By.id("plusminus_housing_type"));
    Actions actions = new Actions(browser);
    actions.moveToElement(expand).click().perform();//ERROR ! Does not reveal housing types.
    WebElement house = browser.findElement(By.id("ul_housing_type"));
    WebElement apartment = house.findElement(By.xpath("//li[contains(., 'apartment')]//input"));
    apartment.click();
}
```

When I use javascript instead of actions, the menu is revealed, but I get an exception that the "apartment" element is not clickable. To fix that, I have to click it with javascript as well as shown below:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", anyElement);
```

Surprisingly, actions or javascript is not needed to reveal the "neighborhoods" menu.

I don't want to just make the code work. I need to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `Expand` button with id `plusminus_housing_type` is hiding inside scroll bar, selenium do click on element as well as user do click on the page.

Suppose you are the user, and you are going to click on `Expand` button, **you can not click on this button without scrolling down** to reach this button.

According to same behavior selenium `click()` method works while `JavaScript` click just only trigger the event internally which is not correct with user's point.

So in this reason you are unable to click by using simple selenium `click`, Here you need to implement  `WebDriverWait` and provide appropriate wait `ExpectedConditions` for interacting to these elements after **scrolling down** as below :-

```
browser.get(url);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 10);

//Now find the expand button first
WebElement expand = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("plusminus_housing_type")));

//Now scroll down and reach to the button
((JavascriptExecutor) browser).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", expand);
//Now click on expand button
expand.click();

//Now wait until apartment checkbox visible and then find 
WebElement apartment = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("apartment_1")));
//Now click on apartment check box      
apartment.click();
```

Comment: What does visibilityOfElementLocated really do ? The API doc is not clear. "An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0." What does it mean by "displayed" ? Can the element be seen in the viewport or screen ? OR, the element can be seen only if you scroll to it ?

Comment: Looks like javascript does not work sometimes. Here is a new question about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948096/why-cant-i-clear-an-input-field-with-javascript

Comment: Here Visibility means element can be viewable on screen and could be receive the event. So in your case it would be possible by scrolling and then expanding...